# Taking camera location from an average

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to keep a camera centered around a group of spheres ( that each player can control through "vertical" and "horizontal". I'm trying to use the same code from the spheres to move the camera ( with a few adjustments ). I know the rb needs to be removed because the camera is not a rigid body, I just don't know how to do it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{

public float speed;

private Rigidbody rb;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveHorizontal2 = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal2");
    float moveHorizontal3 = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal3");
    float moveHorizontal4 = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal4");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    float moveVertical2 = Input.GetAxis("Vertical2");
    float moveVertical3 = Input.GetAxis("Vertical3");
    float moveVertical4 = Input.GetAxis("Vertical4");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(((moveHorizontal+moveHorizontal2+moveHorizontal3+moveHorizontal4)/4), 0.0f, ((moveVertical+moveVertical2+moveVertical3+moveVertical4)/4));

    rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
}
}
```

Comment: If you have three (say) positions, they are all Vector3. To find the middle you very simply do this `Vector3 middle = (a+b+c)/3f;`

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure what the question is asking. Going with the title, I would suggest you lookup averaging of vectors.

If I have horizontal and vertical vectors : these 2 for instance

```
3, 3
3, 3
```

The average is worked out the same way as any integer.

```
 3   3
+3   3

=6   6
```

Then divide by the total count (2)

Average is 3, 3

If I had

```
  1, 4
  2, 7
 -5, 33
  5, 4
= 3, 48

Divide by 4:
0.75 (depends on accuracy, round to 1?)

1, 12
```

This should give you a vector around the 'middle' of the vectors you have on hand.